# Flex 3: How do I get URL

Tags: apache-flex, url

I'm setting up a twitter button on my Flex 3 site. I've got it working, but the URL info it uses is static--- www.mysite.com, for example. I want to make it so that twitter button interacts with whatever "page" the user is looking at. But, I don't know how to grab the current URL. So, for example, if the user is looking at: http://www.mysite.com/#view=2 how do I get that information. Or if they're looking at http://www.mysite.com/#view=44, how do I get that the URL?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
var browserUrl:String = ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
```

Comment: Where would this go in the following widget? <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="This is a tweet!" data-via="ElonMusk" data-hashtags="something" data-lang="en" data-dnt="true" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use JavaScript to obtain the location object.
Look into the AS3 class ExternalInterface.